# Perl. Can't enter to a while (<>) loop

Tags: git, perl

I have a piece of code in perl, that is used for a **pre-recieve** git hook (it restricts the size of files, that can be pushed. It is on the server side). The problem is that I can't enter the **while (<>)** loop, I don't really know, how it works. Could you explain it to me? Why can't I enter a loop?

Thanks in advance!

The code of while loop is here:

```
while (<>) {
  print "I can't enter here, so I cannot block the files!!!"
  chomp;
  my ($old, $new, $ref) = split / /, $_;
  my %visited = ();
  my $log = ($old =~ /^0+$/ ? `/usr/bin/git log --pretty=%H $new`
                            : `/usr/bin/git log --pretty=%H $old..$new`);
  for my $commit (split /\n/, $log) {
    # pick new files in each commit
    for my $entry (split /\n/,
      ($old =~ /^0+$/
        ? `/usr/bin/git diff-tree --no-commit-id -r $commit`
        : `/usr/bin/git diff-tree --no-commit-id -r $old..$commit`)) {
      if ($entry =~ /^:\d+ \d+ \w+ (\w+) \w+\t(.*)$/ && !$visited{$1}) {
        my $sha = $1;
        my $name = $2;
        unless ($sha =~ /^0+$/) {
          $visited{$sha} = 1;
          # check file size
          my $size = `/usr/bin/git cat-file -s $sha`;
          chomp $size;
          # reject file size is greater than limit
          if ($size > $limit) {
            my $shortsha = substr($commit, 0, 10);
            my $hsize = hsize($size);
            my $hlimit = hsize($limit);
            print "'$name' of size $hsize in $shortsha is over $hlimit limit";
            $hasBadFiles = 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should explain how you run the script from command line, what are the arguments and similar details.

Comment: @Сухой27: He said it was a [git pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 1):

`<>` - the diamond operator - is also known and used as `<ARGV>`:

[perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> ARGV
>   The special filehandle that iterates over command-line filenames in @ARGV . Usually written as the null filehandle in the angle operator <> . Note that currently ARGV only has its magical effect within the <> operator; elsewhere it is just a plain filehandle corresponding to the last file opened by <> . In particular, passing *ARGV as a parameter to a function that expects a filehandle may not cause your function to automatically read the contents of all the files in @ARGV .

```
while ( <> ) {
```

Tells perl to either:

- Open files specified as arguments, and read them line by line.
- Read STDIN line by line.

Comment: so what file is it trying to open in my case? What can be a reason, that I it can not get inside of loop?

Comment: @IlyaBogomolnyy It is not entering in the loop because of no command line arguments. Check how this script is running and what cmd line arguments are there.

Comment: And if there's no arguments - it's reading STDIN. And so nothing is getting piped to it, either.

Comment: It seems to be doing the right thing. Git pre-receive hooks receive their input on STDIN.

Comment: @DaveCross, so why is it empty in my case? How can I find it out on the server site?

Comment: @IlyaBogomolnyy: No idea I'm afraid. Might have more time to investigate later today.

Comment: @IlyaBogomolnyy Are you sure the hook is getting called after all? I'm thinking of the correct filename and execution flags. Is it called `pre-receive` and has `chmod 755`?

Comment: It is getting called. And it works porperly till while(<>). I checked it by using a "print" command in different places.

Comment: @PerlDuck maybe I can use some commands inside of git hook, to clarify, why does it happening?

Comment: So there is some code _before_ the `while(<>)`? Show that as well.

Comment: @Sobrique: *"`<>` - the diamond operator - is also known and used as `<ARGV>`"* No.   `<ARGV>` is different from `<>`, whose behaviour depends on whether there is anything in `@ARGV`. `<>` is effectively `@ARGV ? <ARGV> : <STDIN>`. (It actually does it by setting `@ARGV = ('-')` if it is empty before reading from `ARGV`.) (That's a list of one string, not a smiley!)